# js builder file no find exception

Tags: javascript, jsbuilder

I try to run JSBuilder script (*.bat file):

```
"java.exe" -jar JSBuilder2.jar --projectFile "script_name.jsb2" --homeDir "C:\Users\Tomasz\Desktop" --verbose
```

in script_name.jsb2 I got:

```
{
    "projectName": "Name",
    "deployDir":   "\\Name\\Deploy",
    "licenseText": "licence",
    "pkgs": [{
        "name":    "Name",
        "file":    "Name.js",
        "isDebug": true,
        "fileIncludes": [ {
            "text":  "file1.js",
            "path":  "\\Name\\"
        },{
            "text":  "file2.js",
            "path":  "\\Name\\"
        }]
    }],
    "resources":   []
}
```

and I got error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\Name\file1.js
```

I can not find how `null` is coming from ? files and folders (homeDir) existing, - this is Windows 7, on different one (XP) similar script has no such problems...

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *.bat file parameter `--projectFile` should be provided with full path like `c:\....` it make the difference